# Clothes pass through the mesh

Tags: animation, mesh, cloth-simulation

My clothe mesh pass through my character mesh in clothe simulation. How can I change that ? I precise that I can't hide the body inside because I want a clothe a little bit transparent to obtend more realism.

Initial form :

[image]

Aspect after some frames with the movement of the simulation clothe :

[image]

Thank for your attention !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select your body, then go to the *Physics* menu and click *Collision* so that it can interact with the cloth

[image]